# Setting the Threshold for a Perceptron

Tags: python, scikit-learn, perceptron

How can I set the threshold for a single layer perceptron?
I have

```py
    import numpy as np
    import sklearn
    from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron

    xs = np.array([
      # x1 x2
        0, 0, #m1
        0, 1,
        1, 0,
        1, 1
    ]).reshape(4, 2)

    ys = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1]).reshape(4,)

    ppn = Perceptron(max_iter=10, eta0=0.2, random_state=0)

    ppn.fit(xs, ys)
```

What I wanna do is to train the `ppn` weights, with initial
weights=(0,0), eta=0.2, threshold=0,5

Eg. for m1, initial: ys=1:

```
net= w1*x1+w2*x2 = 0*1+0*1=0 
f(net) = 1, if net>=threshold else 0, 
f(0) = 0  # because, 0 < 0.5
error = 0.2*(1-0) = 0.2
weight_update_w1 = 0+0.2*1
```

The learning should stop, if once for all m's no 
weight update is performed.

How can I set the threshold for `ppn` to `0.5`?

Comment: Could you please tell us in more detail what are you working with? What are your imports?

Comment: I've only taken machine learning recently in engineering school and I mainly do C++, but it is my understanding that you don't use non-zero biases, but you instead bias the perceptron layer to -0.5. The reason for this is that it slows the computer down to have to compare to anything but zero due to load times. Tell me if I'm wrong here so I can get is straight. Thanks. I will pull out college textbook if requested.

Comment: I honestly didn't get why you need to set the intercept to -0.5, or any value for that matter. Scikit-learn automatically fits (learns) the intercept during training. If you really need to do that, there is an indirect way of doing it.